# How to access elements in array of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am new to iOS development as well as JSON. I am stuck on something and would really appreciate any help. I researched this quite a bit but could not find anything directly applicable.

So, I retrieve a dictionary using the following code in my model class. This is called from the view controller. Here, getJSON is called first.

```
private func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData{
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!
}

private func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) {

    var error: NSError?
    self.dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

}
```

I get the following back...

[image]

I wrote a class called Comment that will be used in my app. I want to take the info between each set of {} in the dictionary value and assign id, content, etc to the corresponding properties of a comment object. How do I do this? I can't figure out how to parse this. Is there a library? I looked around online but nothing seems to be applicable.

Anyhow, thanks a lot for your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: `response` looks like a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`. And you're the first one asking about JSON and Swift. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried parsing it myself.I tried a few libraries online but they're all convoluted. Most of the posts I see on stackoverflow don't have the same structure as what I am getting. So, it's been difficult to find something to mimic.

Comment: At this stage it has nothing to do with JSON, and there's nothing to "parse".  You have a dictionary containing the element "response".  That element is an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Understand that, in a log, `{ }` surrounds a dictionary, while `(  )` surrounds an array.  Dictionary entries consist of a key (usually a string) and an associated value (which may be string, NSNumber, or any other object).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It was a huge help. I got it to work.